# live validation with ajax & rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using ruby on rails 3. with UJS and jquery
I am trying to generate an AJAX form.
As we know that the form remains as a normal form even though it is AJAX only remote-data=>true gets added.

The form is checked on the fly for remote-data=>true and then it performs and ajax request.

Now How do I perform live validation after the submit button is clicked.

What I want is .--
When the submit button is clicked all the valications should be performed on client side and then if everything is perfect I want the form to be submitted. If there are any eroors the form should not be submitted.

An idea ?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations

Even better than what you are suggesting imho.

Comment: Thanks.I know that way. But I want to validate only when submit is clicked.

Comment: I would dig into the javascript code of that gem and override them with my own client-side code. The validation-parts of it is really nice and should be easy enough to modify considering the dynamic nature of javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try doing that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing this 
so every form which is a remote form check if the fields are valid.
If the fields are valid the return true from ajax:before send else return false.

```
$('.remote_form').live('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, elements){

if(validate_fields(this))
 {
        return true;
 }
 else
     return false;
      });
```

Note : Validate_fields is user-defined function to check for validations.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this two Posts:

the validate plugin is out of the box "onSubmit" responsive.

With the tutorial should should come along to implement ajax validation as well.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
http://sleekd.com/tutorials/jquery-validation-in-ruby-on-rails/